# Data Pre-fetching to Overlap Memory Access and Computation CUDA

Tags: cuda

In order to optimize the performance of my cuda kernel, I tried to pre-fetch (or pre-read) data from global memory into my kernel to try to overlap memory bandwidth and computation.

My implementations were based on the logic below:

```
// Original code
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
}

// Code with pre-fetch
temp = array[0];
for (i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
    temp2 = array[i+1];
    sum += temp;
    temp = temp2;
}
sum += temp;
```

The idea was to try to concurrently execute temp2 = array[i+1] and sum+=temp so that I could overlap the execution of the current element with the data fetch of the next element.

Such an implementation yielded a very small increase in speed-up (about 3%) as compared to the original. I am wondering if there is an explicit way to tell cuda to overlap the execution of these 2 lines of code? How can I ensure that these lines run concurrently enabling a nice overlap between reading global memory and performing some computation

Thank you for your time in reading my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your example can show only a minimal increase in performance, if any, because the two operations (loading from global memory and performing a sum) have very different speeds: accessing global memory is much slower.

The typical approach is to load data from global memory to shared memory, than perform *a lot* of computations with data sitting there (note: shared memory is equivalent to a shared L1 cache, in terms of performance: the main difference with respect to an L1 cache, is that it must be explicitly addressed).

The typical example (see [this link in the Cuda C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#shared-memory)) is with matrix multiplications: you load a N by N square block of the two matrices in shared-memory (that are N*N elements), and perform the partial products (that are N*N*N operations): N operations per element.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @Sigismondo!!

However, my application requires only 1 global read for every global write hence using shared memory will only make it slower (as that would involve 1 global memory read + 1 shared memory read for every write operation). Is there any other way to increase performance for such an application?

Comment: not much actually... if your data is coming from the CPU the main bottleneck will be the transfer through the PCI express bus (cudaMemcpy()'s). If not, you can try to do your best by coalescing correctly the accesses, but you will be far away from the theoretical performance of the GPU, because of the memory bottleneck.